# Unable to run windows iso VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I am trying to run windows 10 through VirtualBox. But, whenever I try that, it terminates with an error showing some error message. Is there any way to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: The error message seems clear enough, it fails to open the ISO file. It seems as if you've moved the ISO away from where it was located when the virtual machine was created. Just mounting it from its correct current location would fix it.

Comment: Actually no!! I have not moved it. The iso was downloaded and saved in this location.

Comment: The pathname starts with `/mnt`, indicating it's a on a separately mounted disk. Is that disk still mounted?

Comment: yes, the disk is mounted.

Comment: Hold on, now I see. Why does it refer to the ISO file as the virtual machine? How did you set this up? The ISO file should be attached to the virtual machine's virtual CD drive.

Comment: sorry I did not get what you meant. would you please explain?

Comment: The error message says that it tries to use an ISO file as the virtual machine. This would obviously fail. Create a new virtual machine and add the ISO file to the machine's virtual CD reader. Then boot the virtual machine.

Comment: thanks it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that VirtualBox tries to use an ISO file as the virtual machine. An ISO file is an image of a CD or DVD, possibly containing software and installation sets.  This is not a virtual machine by itself but installation media that you likely need to boot your virtual machine from.

Create a new virtual machine and add the ISO file to the machine's virtual CD reader. Then boot the virtual machine.